# dplyr-how to insert NA values when the column sort order changes

Tags: r, sorting, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to insert `NA` values when the column values are changed from the `increasing` order to mixed order. But if increasing order continues logically after this mixed ordered rows, its ok to keep those rows too.

If all the rows do not have the increasing order, replace those row values with `NA`. (means all the rows mixed sort ordered)

In addition, any column which can keep the sort sequence at least 5 numbers inside of its rows can pass (can keep its rows those with ordered parts). Else, replace `NA` values those rows who cannot pass this logic.

Its best for me to do this process with `dplyr` . I tried to do this but cannot came up with the idea:(.

```
dt_new <- dt%>%
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(ifelse(.....
```

example data

```
set.seed(123) 
C1 = c(1:10,7,8,11,12)
C2 = c(2:12,7,13,12)
C3 = sample(1:14)
C4 = c(1:14)
C5 = c(sample(1:9),5,6,7,8,10)

dt <- data.frame(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)

       C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
#   1   1  2  5  1  1
#   2   2  3 11  2  8
#   3   3  4 14  3  2
#   4   4  5 10  4  9
#   5   5  6 13  5  7
#   6   6  7  1  6  4
#   7   7  8 12  7  3
#   8   8  9  7  8  5
#   9   9 10  4  9  6
#   10 10 11  3 10  5
#   11  7 12  6 11  6
#   12  8  7  2 12  7 
#   13 11 13  2 13  8
#   14 12 12  9 14 10
```

the output Which I look for

```
       C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
#   1   1  2 NA  1  1
#   2   2  3 NA  2 NA
#   3   3  4 NA  3  2 
#   4   4  5 NA  4 NA
#   5   5  6 NA  5 NA
#   6   6  7 NA  6 NA
#   7   7  8 NA  7  3
#   8   8  9 NA  8 NA
#   9   9 10 NA  9 NA
#   10 10 11 NA 10 5
#   11 NA 12 NA 11 6
#   12 NA NA NA 12 7
#   13 11 13 NA 13 8
#   14 12 NA NA 14 9
```

Comment: Why is `dt$C5[1]` becoming `NA` ? I had expect the 1 to stay there. (Well that's not the only thing I don't understand, I pass)

Comment: @Tensibai pass means if at least 5 rows can show increasing order sequence at that C5 column its ok to keep them. Other rows should be  `NA`

Comment: So you would keep only blocks of 5 continuous(increasing) rows ? Sorry but your expected output is quite hard to match with the input and the logic is unclear to me

Comment: @Tensibai if so can you at least provide an answer if the logic order changes part.

Comment: You should fix your expected output regarding your input. As I actually understand your question C5 row should be c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,3,5,6,NA,NA,7,8,10) or maybe c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,5,6,7,8,10) or maybe a whole NA I can't decide which one exactly

Comment: All in all I've the feeling this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), trying to fix something on the path which could maybe be avoided with another approach

Comment: @Tensibai oh Ok I understand your point. The second one you offered is ok in this sense. c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,5,6,7,8,10)

Comment: I think it's the hardest one to obtain, and still the specs of why it should be this are unclear to me, which does not help thinking about a solution :/

Comment: @Tensibai ok for now at least lets forget about `C5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quite far-fetched solution... It works for the previous output, but not with the current C5: it will remove any values before the first match to a series of 5 consecutive increasing values.

1. Find out if there is a series of 5 increasing values in the variable. Compare values with `lag`. Use `rle` to look for a serie of 5.
2. If no serie, return a vector of NA of `length=length(var)`
3. Else

   1. Compare each value to the previous one, remove if inferior
   2. If the previous value has been removed, make another pass to compare to the last non-removed value. Remove if inferior. Repeat while values are being removed.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

co <- function(var){
  r <- rle(lag(var) < var)
  d <- data.frame(v=r$values,
                  l=r$lengths,
                  c=cumsum(r$lengths))
  idx <- which(d$l > 3 & d$v==TRUE)[1] - 1
  id <- d$c[idx]


  v <- rep(NA,length(var))
  if(!is.na(id)) {
    p <- id:length(v)
    v[p] <- ifelse(var[p] > lag(var[p]),
                              var[p],
                              NA)
    v[id] <- var[id]

    previous.na <- sum(is.na(lag(v[p])))

    if(previous.na > 1) {
      current.na <- 0

      while(current.na != previous.na)
      { 
        previous.na <- sum(is.na(v))
        v[p][is.na(lag(v[p]))][-1] <- ifelse(v[p][is.na(lag(v[p]))][-1] > lag(na.locf(v[p]))[is.na(lag(v[p]))][-1],
                                             v[p][is.na(lag(v[p]))][-1],
                                             NA)
        v[id] <- var[id]
        current.na <- sum(is.na(v))
      }

    }
  }

  print(var)
  return(v)
}
mutate_each(dt,funs = funs(co))
```

output

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1   1  2 NA  1 NA
2   2  3 NA  2 NA
3   3  4 NA  3 NA
4   4  5 NA  4 NA
5   5  6 NA  5 NA
6   6  7 NA  6 NA
7   7  8 NA  7 NA
8   8  9 NA  8 NA
9   9 10 NA  9 NA
10 10 11 NA 10  5
11 NA 12 NA 11  6
12 NA NA NA 12  7
13 11 13 NA 13  8
14 12 NA NA 14 10
```

I used this dataset (repeat set.seed for C5)

```
C1 = c(1:10,7,8,11,12)
C2 = c(2:12,7,13,12)
set.seed(123) 
C3 = sample(1:14)
C4 = c(1:14)
set.seed(456) 
C5 = c(sample(1:9),5,6,7,8,10)
dt <- data.frame(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
```

Comment: @scoa thanks man for your time and effort for writing such a complicated code. By the way how can you write down this kind of logical flow which I cant do? do you have suggestion book or wep page for studying?

Comment: @scoa  and if I want to generalize this `co` function for also `decreasing` order which part should be changed?

Comment: To change the order, you would need to change the comparison sign every time `v` is compared to `lag(v)` or `var` to `lag(var)`. `var[p] > lag(var[p])` becomes `var[p] < lag(var[p])`, etc.

Comment: I really appreciated your effort to write  `co` function. On the other hand as I mentioned in my previous comment, is it possible to utilize this function for other datasets with also decreasing order. Such as I tried for this data set `C1 = c(1,0.1,0.001,0.0001,0.02,0.01)

C2 = c(0,1, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0002)
C3 = c(0,1,0.01,1,0.001,0.2)

df <- data.frame(C1,C2,C3)` and got all `NA` values for their rows.

Comment: @Alexander have you seen my previous comment? It explains how to do this. In this new dataset, there is no series of 5 decreasing values so it's normal you get all NAs.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply. Yes I checked your previous comment. I modified the `co` function according to your instructions. now I can get numbers with decreasing order if there is a series with decreasing order 5. But I come to realize that so far I dont need those parts such as in `C1` 11&12 and `C2` 13. 
I want to set them to `NA` also.
I tried many things but I failed. Would you suggest something about it?

Comment: `co <- function(var){
  r <- rle(lag(var) < var)
  d <- data.frame(v=r$values,
                  l=r$lengths,
                  c=cumsum(r$lengths))
  idx_s <- d$c[which(d$l > 3 & d$v==TRUE)[1] - 1]
  idx_e <- d$c[which(d$l > 3 & d$v==TRUE)[1]]
  
  v <- rep(NA,length(var))
  if(!is.na(idx_s))  v[idx_s:idx_e] <- var[idx_s:idx_e]
  
  print(var)
  return(v)
}`

Comment: thanks but getting error about maybe missing `}` somewhere?

Comment: the statement after the if(!is.na) should be on the same line, or in brackets

Comment: do you mean this  `if(!is.na(idx_s)){
                       v[idx_s:idx_e] <- var[idx_s:idx_e] 
                     print(var) } `

Comment: yep. You can omit the brackets if the whole statement is on one line

Comment: ok i fixed that now it works for the example that I provided here but it started not to work for my real data. Ok I will put snapshot of my real data looks like below the main question. I really need to have this because I have tons of data to reshape like this. I hope you will save my life:)

Comment: i think a new question would be more appropriate, with a link to this one

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks man I really appriciate your help. best regards